# Calculus: What's wrong with this computation?

Tags: calculus, limits

Given: $\lim_{x\to\infty} (x) = \infty$

the following substitution of  $1/\infty = 0$, is resulting in undefined value:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}{ 1\over 1/x } = {1\over 0} = \text{Undeterminable}$$

Comment: the "rule" $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) / g(x) = \lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) / \lim_{x\to \infty}  g(x)$ has some conditions / assumptions

Comment: $1$ divided by something $\to 0^+$ is not indeterminate.

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0):

The expression $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{1/x}$ talks about the behaviour of the expression $$\frac{1}{1/x} = \frac{x}{1} = x,$$ as $x$ gets "arbitrarily" large.

As user251257 points out, there are some rules on when the limit operator can be push through expressions. It's clear from above that $$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{1/x} = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} x = \infty,$$ even though it is very well the case that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} 1/x = 0$.

Comment: I wonder how you can answer something which is not a question.

Comment: @mathreadler Unfortunately the question is just in the title.

Comment: Why is it unfortunate?